# String Replacement in C

Tags: c, string, substring

Got an issue with working with a string in C. I have a string like this :

```
".>0and.<300"
```

Or

```
".>0 and .<280"
```

Or

```
".&gt;=0 and .&lt;=280"
```

The dot is representing the value x. I need to create a simpler string looking like:

```
"minimum:maximum"
```

eg `0:300`. I tried to start looking for `<` and `and` to take the value in.

```
char *open = strrchr(string, '<');
char *end = strrchr(string, 'and');
```

Thks for any help !

Comment: Look up "parsing". You need a simple parser for your string that will split it by `and` and extract the bounds.

Comment: You could use regular expressions. There's no built-in support for regular expressions, but there is [POSIX support](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/re_comp.html).

Comment: @dreamlax he's trying to solve a problem. suggest him to use regular expressions. now he'll have two problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Replace all non-digit characters with `' '`.
2. Trim spaces at the start.
3. Trim spaces between numbers, leave only one.
4. Put `'\0'` after last digit.
5. Replace the one space with `':'`.

If the numbers may be inversed in order, you may use this (code this time, as you wish):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))

int main()
{
  char src[] = ".>1220and.<300";
  char dstBuf[64]="ERROR";
  char* num1 = NULL;
  char* num2 = NULL;
  char* ptr = src;
  int indigit = 0;

  for (;*ptr; ptr++) {
    if (isdigit(*ptr)) {
      if (indigit == 0) {
        if (num1 == NULL) num1 = ptr;
        else              num2 = ptr;
        indigit = 1;
      }
    } else {
      indigit = 0;
    }
  }
  if (num1 != NULL && num2 != NULL) {
    int n1 = strtoll(num1, NULL, 10);
    int n2 = strtoll(num2, NULL, 10);
    sprintf(dstBuf, "%d:%d", MIN(n1,n2), MAX(n1,n2));
  } else if (num1 != NULL) {
    sprintf(dstBuf, "%s", num1);
  }

  printf("%s\n", dstBuf);

}
```

Comment: @Grapsus how about he writes it on his own? It's a fish vs fishing problem, if he writes on his own, le learns something. Otherwise my time's wasted, because I already know how to write it and he hasn't learnt a thing.

Comment: I didn't say that so we do OP's homework. I said it because you suggest a lot of operations that are tedious in a low level language. If you think that "Trim spaces between numbers, leave only one." is the `C` way here, show us the code.

Comment: Problem with this is that sometimes the maximum number can be before the minimum one, so it wont work. Sometimes I also get only one number, and sometimes 0.

Comment: I don't want to troll, but what your code does has nothing to do with what you said...

Comment: @grapsus yep, it's different if you have to check min-max ordering. I've stated this. If you're talking about the fishing thing - yep, you're right again.

Answer (score 0):

How about finding the two numbers and ordering them with min and max ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MIN(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))

int main(){
    char s[] = ".>=0 and .<=280";
    char *ptr = s;
    int a, b;

    while( ! isdigit(*ptr)) ptr++;
    a = atoi(ptr);
    while(isdigit(*ptr)) ptr++;
    while( ! isdigit(*ptr)) ptr++;
    b = atoi(ptr);

    printf("%d:%d\n", MIN(a, b), MAX(a, b));

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that my code assumes that the string is well formed, you should add safety checks for the real thing.

**EDIT**

Here is a very basic parser that handles all cases and that does some safety checks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    char s[] = ".>=0 and .<=280";
    char *ptr = s;
    int num;
    unsigned char equals, gt, lt;

    while(*ptr){
        /* consume the stuff before the digit */
        equals = gt = lt = 0;
        while(*ptr && ! isdigit(*ptr)){
            switch(*ptr){
                case '=':
                    equals = 1; break;
                case '<':
                    lt = 1; break;
                case '>':
                    gt = 1; break;
            }
            ptr++;
        }
        /* consume the digit */
        num = atoi(ptr);
        while(*ptr && isdigit(*ptr)) ptr++;

        /* do your stuff according to (gt, lt, equals, num) */
        printf("found comparison: gt=%d lt=%d equals=%d num=%d\n", gt, lt, equals, num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is how it works:

```
$ ./test 
found comparison: gt=1 lt=0 equals=1 num=0
found comparison: gt=0 lt=1 equals=1 num=280
```

If your need becomes any more complex than this, you should really look at proper parsing and lexing tools.

Comment: Thks a lot for this answer whic helps me a lot ! What do you mean by safety check? Another thing, sometimes my string can contain only one number, sometimes 0. How can I handle these cases? Until now I just have a lot of sgmentation fault by trying